# Breakpoints ignored when filename > 60 chars

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

My lua source file have a filename > 60 chars (with needful non absolute path)
When the debugger is running, LuaDebugger.cs performs a breakpoint check:

```
breakpoint = GetBreakpoint(src, line);
```

GetBreakpoint call GetFile() but it always returns null because

```
String.Compare(fileName, file.FileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

fails

```
when filename = luaDebug.shortsrc
```

(shortsrc is defined by  `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 60/*LUA_IDSIZE*/)]`
)

If I use `filename = luaDebug.source.toString().Substring(1)` it works but I do not want to change luainterface-debugger source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to change the source code, you have little options, because it's the sourcecode itself what's giving you roblems (I'd assume it's that LUA_IDSIZE const).

Without modifying the code, the options you have are very limited. They all involve giving up on having more than 60 character paths.